# Get image from JSON String in JAVA

Tags: java, android

I am sending JSON string to Java from php, that consists of some string type data and encoded image. In jJva inputStream is converted to BufferedReader and to String. Now string looks like `{"name": "xxx", "image":agrewfefe...}`
Is there any possible way to decode the string that represents image to bitmap or I have to send image in other stream?

Comment: You can't safely assume that if you translate an image to text it won't contain characters that are considered invalid in JSON (or that break the JSON syntax, like " or ' or : or ,).

Comment: Your (sorta) snippit isn't valid JSON for one (strings have to be quoted). Aside from that, what @11684 says above; You'd need to do something such as Base64 encode your image to avoid breaking JSON.

Comment: Can you _decode_ Base64? @BrianRoach

Comment: Hey, learned something today! @BrianRoach

Comment: @11684 - That's the entire point of Base64 encoding/decoding ;) It's not encryption - it's to encode binary data into a printable text format. (I'm guessing by your second comment you just looked it up :) )

Comment: Yes, I always assumed it was something of the same class as SHA1 etc, those hashes you supposedly can't break. After seeing your comment I did a quick google and found a site mentioning it is to indeed transform it into a printable format. @BrianRoach

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you need to [Base64 encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) your image.

As it is you're not guaranteed that the characters you generate are printable, or that they won't break the JSON format.

There are a number of Base64 encoding/decoding libraries. A commonly used one is included in the [Apache commons (codec) library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Here's a simple usage example from http://www.kodejava.org/examples/375.html

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Base64Encode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello World";

        //
        // The encodeBase64 method take a byte[] as the paramater. The byte[] 
        // can be from a simple string like in this example or it can be from
        // an image file data.
        //
        byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(hello.getBytes());

        //
        // Print the encoded byte array
        //
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encoded));

        //
        // Print the encoded string
        //
        String encodedString = new String(encoded);
        System.out.println(hello + " = " + encodedString);
    }
}
```

On the sending side you would use that encoded string for you JSON "image" field. Other end you would parse the JSON then decode your Base64 string back to the image.

**Edit to add:** Just re-read your question (I only noted the tags originally and missed the PHP part) - on the PHP side you'd need to use `base64_encode`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Base64 encoding is the way to go. But instead of manually doing that, just use [Jackson JSON library](http://jackson.codehaus.org), which automatically Base64 encodes/decodes binary data (anything declared as `byte[]`). So something like

```
public class Request {
  public String name;
  public byte[] image;
}

Request req = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new URL("http://my.service.com/getImage?id=123"),
  Request.class);
```

Comment: Good call. I actually didn't know Jackson had that feature; learn something new every day.